# Let g be a non-decreasing function defined on the real line and bounded above by 1?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $g$ be a non-decreasing function defined on the real line and bounded above by 1:

Assume $g(0)\ge 0$. Prove that $P(X<0)\le 1-E[g(X)-g(0)]$

Attempt:

Consider: $1-E[g(X)-g(0)]=1-E[g(X)-g(0)(X \ge 0)]-E[g(X)-g(0)(X < 0)]$

Since $E[g(X)-g(0)(X < 0)]<0$ then $-E[g(X)-g(0)(X < 0)]>0$

Then $1-E[g(X)-g(0)(X \ge 0)]-E[g(X)-g(0)(X < 0)]> 1-E[g(X)-g(0)(X \ge 0)]$

Note since $1\ge g(X)-g(0)$, then $1-E[g(X)-g(0)(X \ge 0)\ge 1-E[X\ge0]=P(X<0)$.

Concluding,  $P(X<0)\le 1-E[g(X)-g(0)]$

Is my logic correct? The question asks also to find an example where $g(0)<0$ then $P(X<0)> 1-E[g(X)-g(0)]$ Have not been able to find an example can someone provide one?

Comment: It is correct except that you have written strict inequalities instead of loose inequalitiies at many places.

Comment: Where exactly is there a strict inequality where a loose inequality should be?

Comment: For example $E[g(X)-g(0)(X < 0)]<0$ may be false. What if $X \geq 0$ almost surely?

Comment: I see. Thank you